# How to auto-detect filetype in pastebinit?

Tags: bash, scripting, file-descriptors, utilities

I use [pastebinit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pastebinit.1.html) to share snippets. As you can see, it has a `-f` switch so the rendered webpage highlights the uploaded file depending on the format of the file (like `-f python` or `-f bash`).

Now, I want to somehow auto-detect the snippet file-type, so I would not need to manually give the proper switch.

1. Is it possible to do so in pastebinit?
2. Is it possible to wrap it in a script and detect the file type using some other utility?

For example, I tried utilizing `file` but I don't think it is useful here:

```bash
$ file --mime-type -b main.c 
text/x-c  # Should have been C

$ file --mime-type -b script.py 
text/x-python  # Should have been Python

$ file --mime-type -b README.md 
text/plain  # Should have been Markdown

$ file --mime-type -b ~/.bashrc 
text/plain  # Should have been Bash

$ file --mime-type -b ~/blah/main.cpp 
text/x-c  # Should have been Cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic tool that can always identify the type of the
given file just by looking at its contents or name. `file` and other similar
tools can just take an educated guess which doesn't have to always
correct because some file formats can overlap (a funny fact -
[Slackware Linux packages logfiles used to be recognized as Quake
files by
file](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/packages-logfiles-are-recognized-as-quake-files-by-%60file%27-4175563926))
or because some file formats are not specific enough to be easily
distinguishable from other file formats (the whole point of Markdown
was to make .md files look like regular text files).

In your example though all files except `.bashrc` have different
extension so you can write a script that could use them to identify
the type but you should remember that on *nix systems file extensions
matter only for some programs and that kernel doesn't care. For
example, create `script.sh` shell script:

```
$ cat << EOF > script.sh
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> echo hi
> EOF
```

Set an executable bit and run it:

```
$ chmod +x ./script.sh
$ ./script.sh
hi
```

Rename it to `script.md` and run it:

```
$ mv ./script.sh ./script.md
$ ./script.md
hi
```

As you see we can run it even after renaming it to `script.md`.

It would be *fairly* use to write a tool that guesses filetype based
on the filename's extension in any modern language such as Python or
Bash. Here's an example `whatisthis.sh` in Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]
then
    printf "Usage: %s file_with_extension\n" "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

ext="$(rev <<< "$1" | cut -d . -f1 | rev)"

declare -A extensions=(
    [c]=C
    [py]=Python
    [md]=Markdown
    [cpp]=Cpp
)

printf "%s\n" "${extensions["$ext"]}"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./whatisthis.sh README.md
Markdown
$ ./whatisthis.sh main.py
Python
$ ./whatisthis.sh main.c
C
```

Of course there are plenty, possibly [thousands of different file
extensions for different
filetypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions)
and it's likely that someone has already written a more robust script
that uses file extension to identify the type.

When it comes to `.bashrc` it could be identified by `file` after
adding `#!/usr/bin/env bash` - adding it won't break it because when
it's sourced by each new interactive shell and each line that starts
with `#` is treated as a comment.

To sum up - there is no way to auto-detect a filetype. For the best
results you should combine `file` and look at a file extension but at
the end of the day it's always up to the human user to know what's the
purpose of the given file.